# JMeter Xpath extrator

Tags: xml, xpath, jmeter

I am currently sending SOAP XML requests and receiving a response from a third party API. I am looking to retrieve a particular value that is returned in the response and pass this to a subsequent request that goes back to the same API.

I am using the XPath extractor to achieve this however when I am trying to pass the response variable on, which is returned as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-
open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
.....
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<c:replyMessage xmlns:c="---------------------------">
<c:referenceNumber>84c74155-e260-46f9-98bf-5ba6ee6cbb20</c:referenceNumber>
<c:backgroundCode>5048657036666628204009</c:backgroundCode>
.....
</c:replyMessage>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The fields I am attempting to pass are referenceNumber and backgroundCode using the XPath extractor response/c:referenceNumber however I receive the error

```
Assertion error: false
Assertion failure: true
Assertion failure message: Prefix must resolve to a namespace: c
See log file for further details.
```

Any advise would be greatly appreciated. If you need any more info please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: I strongly recommend you **NOT TO USE XPath extractor**. It is usually difficult to use and its performance is very bad. See [this article](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-response-data-extractors-comparison/) or [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/response-data-extractors-comparison)

Your choices for this task:

1. [SmartMeter's](https://www.smartmeter.io/) [Boundary Body extractor](https://www.smartmeter.io/documentation#toc-et-sm---boundary-body-extractor) - very easy for use, and it is also very fast and has best performance of all.Example how to use it here  [image: Boundary Body extractor configuration]
2. [Regular expression extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) - slower than first one, but still better than XPath extractor. Use it e.g with this regex: `\<c:referenceNumber\>(.*)\<\/c:referenceNumber\>` [image]
3. If I did not convince you, use [XPath extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor). But [I warned you](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-response-data-extractors-comparison/). Use this expression `//soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*[local-name()='replyMessage']/*[local-name()='referenceNumber']`. Do not forget to check *Use Namespaces* [image]

Comment: Hi klingac thanks for providing that feedback.It works perfectly now. I am using the XPath extractor for the moment but based off what you have said, and the article which is a good read, i am definitely going to look at other options going forward.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I didn't want to use another beast (SmartMeter) so I used reqexp...